# Коллективная разработка Eclipse + Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Здравствуйте!
Возможна ли коллективная разработка под android, используя разные среды?
Я пишу на android studio, коллега - в eclipse. Есть приложение для телефонов, написанное коллегой, мне предстоит написать то же самое для планшетов (основываясь на его коде). Т.к. я неопытный программист, коллега склоняет к тому, чтобы писать на eclipse, и не было каких-то косяков, по-моему, с зависимостями и т.д.
Что же делать? Поддаться давлению?)

Comment: Да.........

Comment: @Suvitruf, это значит писать на eclipse? Или вопрос тривиальный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да особых проблем-то нет. Главное, чтобы был одинаковый VCS, смотрящий в одно репо. Каждая IDE будет сохранять свои настройки, но Eclipse будет игнорировать настройки IDE Android Studio, а студии по барабану настройки Eclipse.

Просто в самом начале Eclipse должен выставить в VCS свои исходники, а студия оттуда вытянуть исходники и создать свое окружение на вытянутых исходниках. Далее коммит из студии, и все.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте систему управления зависимостями — maven/gradle/etc. В этом случае вы не будете зависеть от используемой IDE.